# Appium blank screen on Inspector Window

Tags: android, appium, simulator

I see other people have the same problem but couldn't find a solution for it. I can run the app on my Emulator but cannot see anything in `Inspector Window` and this just happens on Windows machine. Any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check the **Pre-Launch Application** on **General Settings**. It works for me to fix the issue.

[image: Image 1]

After Pre-launching. press **Refresh** then you will get the following screen   which will load the app details
[image: Appium Inspector]

Comment: can you select elements on the Display screen?

Comment: No i cannot click on the elements on the Display screen. I can just navigate using the left screen.

Comment: yep, pretty useless compared to their OS X version

Comment: If you want to select the elements of the Screen then i would suggest you to use the [**UiAutomatorviewer** ](http://testdroid.com/news/appium-tip-13-use-inspector-or-uiautomatorviewer-for-ui-element-inspection)

Its alot better than Appium Inspector, specially when you are using on Windows machine.

Comment: Yep, i feel the same its pretty useless compared to Mac version.